# Como accedo a un método de una clase hija aplicando polimorfismo en java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando acceder a un método de una clase que hereda de otra pero instancio la misma aplicando polimorfismo. Tengo la clase padre Aeropuerto:

```
 public class Aeropuerto {
    private String nombre;
    private String ciudad;
    private String pais;
    
    private Compania listaCompanias[]=new Compania[10];
    private int numCompania;
    
//constructor 1
    public Aeropuerto(String nombre, String ciudad, String pais){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.ciudad=ciudad;
        this.pais=pais;
        this.numCompania=0;
    }
    
    //Metodo para insertar una compania en el vector de companias, este mismo se replica en las demás clases que contengan
    //vectores de otras clases
    public void insertarCompanias(String nombre){
        listaCompanias[numCompania]=new Compania(nombre);
        numCompania=numCompania+1;
        //numCompania++;
    }
    //sobrecarga del método insertarCompanias
    public void insertarCompanias(Compania nuevaCompania){
        listaCompanias[numCompania]=nuevaCompania;
        numCompania=numCompania+1;
        
        
    }
   
}
```

De esta herendan las clases Aeropuerto público (que ahora nome interesa):

```
    public class AeropuertoPublico extends Aeropuerto {
    private double subvención;
    //constructor

    public AeropuertoPublico(double subvención, String nombre, String ciudad, String pais) {
        super(nombre, ciudad, pais);
        this.subvención = subvención;
    }
    

}
Y aeropuerto privado que es donde está el método insertarEmpresa(String) y es a quien quiero acceder:

    public class AeropuertoPrivado extends Aeropuerto {
    private String listaEmpresas[];
    private int numEmpresa;

    public AeropuertoPrivado(String nombre, String ciudad, String pais) {
        super(nombre, ciudad, pais);
        this.listaEmpresas=new String [10];
        numEmpresa=0;
    }
    
    public void insertarEmpresas(String empresa){
        listaEmpresas[numEmpresa]=empresa;
        numEmpresa=numEmpresa+1;
    }
}
```

y por último esta es mi clase principal de donde quiero hacer uso del método aplicando polimorfismo en un vector:

```
public class Principal {
private static Aeropuerto listaAeropuerto[]=new Aeropuerto[3];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    listaAeropuerto[0]=new AeropuertoPublico(2500000, "Newbewry", "Bs As", "Argentina");
    listaAeropuerto[0].insertarCompanias(new Compania("LATAM"));
    listaAeropuerto[0].insertarCompanias(new Compania("Aero"));
    listaAeropuerto[1]=new AeropuertoPrivado("Gardel", "Vedia", "Argentina");
}
```

}

No sé como acceder al método insertarEmpresa de AeropuertoPrivado, alguien puede ayudarme??

Comment: podes agregar la clase Compañia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacer un cast del objeto guardado

```
  ((AeropuertoPrivado) listaAeropuerto[1]).insertarEmpresas ("Macdonald");
```

o usar [instanceof](https://javautodidacta.es/como-utilizar-instanceof-java/) esto para saber si el objeto al que apunta la referencia `listaAeropuerto[1]` es una instancia de la clase `AeropuertoPrivado`,que hereda de la clase `Aeropuerto`.

```
if(listaAeropuerto[1] instanceof AeropuertoPrivado c){
            c.insertarEmpresas ("Coca-cola");
            c.insertarEmpresas ("Frezzer corp");
        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Dramaturgo, me sirvió mucho tú respuesta

Comment: Me alegra, :) recuerda que podes marcar como útil una respuesta ,siempre que está te haya ayudado  ,solo dale click al icono de check  ✓  saludos